# Calling a non-const function with a const pointer as argument

Tags: c++

I've read that a non-const member function of a class can only be called on non-const objects.
My question is, why can a non-member function which takes a non-const pointer, be called with a const pointer?
I tried this code:

```
 int k = 10;
 int x = 5;
void func(int *n) {
    n = &k; 
    cout << *n<< ", x: " << x << endl;
}
int main()
{
     int * const ptr=&x; 
     cout << *ptr << endl; //prints 5
     cout <<"x:"<< x << endl; //prints x:5
     //ptr = &k; //compiler error
     cout << "ptr value (address): " << ptr << endl; //prints 001DC038
    func(ptr); //prints 10, x: 5
    cout << "x:" << x << endl; //x: 5
    cout << *ptr << endl; //5
    cout << "ptr value (address): " << ptr; //prints 001DC038
}
```

I'm not sure I understood it right, but the line `func(ptr)` calls `func()` with ptr's value which is &x, and `n=&k` is supposed to change x's address to k's address? but it prints different values for `*n` and `x`, so what exactly was sent to `func()`?
Is the syntax wrong?

Comment: You should read this excellent question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const

Comment: You sent the pointer to `func` _by value_, meaning `n` was a copy of `ptr`. Also `ptr` is a `const` pointer to a non-`const` `int`, not a pointer to a `const int`.

Comment: @S.M. I haven't. What I'm trying to do is to see if it's possible to call a function with a const pointer instead of non-const pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int * const ptr=&x;
```

declares a *immutable* pointer (you can't change the address stored in `ptr`) that points to a *mutable* `int` (you can change the value `ptr` points to).

```
void func(int *n)
```

takes a pointer to a *mutable* `int` by value, no problems here. The mutability of `ptr` is of no concern, because you take a copy anyway. Speaking of taking copies:

```
 n = &k;
```

will only modify where the local variable `n` points. To reflfect changes outside the function you can pass the parameter by reference:

```
//             V
void func(int *&n)
```

And get the expected compiler error, because you can't bind `ptr` to a non-const reference.

Comment: Now it makes sense.. so when a function receives a pointer as argument, it's actually a copy of it (of the address it holds) and not really the pointer itself?
And if so, then in my code the function was called successfully because inside the function `n` is a copy of a non-const pointer?

Comment: @ItamarIvri Correct, it's the same for arguments of any type in C++.

Comment: So what exactly makes the difference between `void func(int *&n)` or `void func(int *n)` ?
How come in the second one the function treats `n` as a non-const pointer, and in the first one as a const pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Here    `int * const ptr=&x;`  the `ptr` itself is **const**, but **not the value pointed to** (pointee).

When passing `ptr` to `void func(int *n)` the value of `ptr` (= content of ptr == memory address of `x`) is **copied** into `n`. But the pointer type is a **pointer to a non-const int** in both cases. So no mismatch here.

If on the other hand, the pointee instead would be made const as:

```
const int * ptr=&x;  // note: placing const before *
```

then you would get a compilation error as expected, because this would allow `func` to change a const object.

Comment: Then `ptr` == value of ptr == address of non-const int x
 while `*&ptr`== value of what's inside the address of ptr == a const pointer to non-const int?

Comment: `&ptr` is address of pointer variable itself. so `*&ptr` will be the same as pointer `ptr`, but it has nothing to do with the value pointed to (`*ptr`).